# Why everything counts from year 1970?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, plist, time

So I've looked around and couldn't really find an answer to this.

I have an iPhone (jailbroke) and I notice in several settings there is a string usually in the .plist files that say something similar to "TimeIntervalSince1970". Now I know that all timers such as these need a base date and time to start with.

But my real question is why 1970?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not everything counts from 1970.  Its the standard time of Unix.

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing points in time,
>   defined as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight proleptic
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970, not counting leap
>   seconds.

[Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

> Early versions of unix measured system time in 1/60 s intervals. This
>   meant that a 32-bit unsigned integer could only represent a span of
>   time less than 829 days. For this reason, the time represented by the
>   number 0 (called the epoch) had to be set in the very recent past. As
>   this was in the early 1970s, the epoch was set to 1971-1-1.
>
> Later, the system time was changed to increment every second, which
>   increased the span of time that could be represented by a 32-bit
>   unsigned integer to around 136 years. As it was no longer so important
>   to squeeze every second out of the counter, the epoch was rounded down
>   to the nearest decade, thus becoming 1970-1-1. One must assume that
>   this was considered a bit neater than 1971-1-1.
>
> Note that a 32-bit signed integer using 1970-1-1 as its epoch can
>   represent dates up to 2038-1-19, on which date it will wrap around to
>   1901-12-13.

[Why is 1/1/1970 the “epoch time”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090869/why-is-1-1-1970-the-epoch-time)

Comment: Which is why on 1/19/2038 there will be what is referred to as "Y2K38".

Comment: In the "not everything uses 1970" department, the Objective-C NSDate class for OS X and iOS uses 1/1/2001.

Answer (score 0):

The [Unix timestamp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) starts on 1st January 1970 and counts up since. Time in terms of days/months/years/etc is calculated from this number, accounting for time zones and other regional differences.

Comment: Here's nice explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090869/why-is-1-1-1970-the-epoch-time